# PyQt signal not emitted in a pyqtSlot after moveToThread

Tags: multithreading, pyqt

So I want to learn using moveToThread and see the effect of calling `onTimeout()` of class `GenericWorker` from a different thread (main thread in this case). The weird thing is that the `finish_sig` in `GenericWorker` never gets emitted (should happen at the last line of `onTimeout()` ). Since it connects to `terminate_thread()` in `Sender` class, it should at least print out a `terminate_thread` in the console, but nothing happens at all.

My original purpose for using it is to emit a signal to quit the thread after `onTimeout()` is done. But now I can only do t.quit() from `main` to quit the thread.

Thank you all for spending time taking care of my question!

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import threading
from time import sleep
import sys

class GenericWorker(QObject):
    finish_sig = pyqtSignal() # this one never gets emitted!

    @pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def onTimeout(self, cmd1, cmd2):
        print 'onTimeout get called from thread ID: '
        print QThread.currentThreadId()
        print 'received cmd 1: ' + cmd1
        print 'received cmd 2: ' + cmd2
        self.finish_sig.emit()    # supposed to emit here!  

class Sender(QObject):
    send_sig = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    terminate_sig = pyqtSignal()
    def emit_sig(self, cmd):
        print 'emit_sig thread ID: '
        print QThread.currentThreadId()
        sleep(1)
        self.send_sig.emit(cmd, '2nd_cmd')

    def terminate_thread(self):
        print 'terminate_thread'
        self.terminate_sig.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print 'Main thread ID: '
    print QThread.currentThreadId()

    t = QThread()
    my_worker = GenericWorker()
    my_worker.moveToThread(t)
    t.start()

    my_sender = Sender()
    my_sender.send_sig.connect(my_worker.onTimeout)
    my_sender.terminate_sig.connect(t.quit)

    my_worker.finish_sig.connect(my_sender.terminate_thread)
    # my_worker.finish_sig.connect(t.quit)

    my_sender.emit_sig('hello')
    sleep(1)
    # my_sender.terminate_thread()
    # t.quit() # this one works
    # t.wait()
    exit(1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output:

```
Main thread ID:
46965006517856
emit_sig thread ID:
46965006517856
onTimeout get called from thread ID:
1111861568
received cmd 1: hello
received cmd 2: 2nd_cmd
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

**UPDATE:**

After referring to @tmoreau and @ekhumoro's answers, there are two key problems with this code:

1. The `exit(1)` is not a proper way to exit, I need to remove this line.
2. I don't have a way to exit the `QApplication`, what I need to do is to add `t.finish.connect(app.quit)` to exit the application. (By the way, the last line `sys.exit(app.exec_())` seems not taking care of the exiting of the `QApplication`)

In sum, there are basically three things that I need to exit: `QThread`, `QApplication` and `sys`, what I missed is to exit `QApplication`. Let me know if my understanding is right or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you exit the program before it's complete.

```
my_sender.emit_sig('hello')
sleep(1) 
exit(1)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`exit()` ends your program, even if the thread has not finished running, hence the error:

> QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

If you remove `sleep(1)`, you'll see the program stops even earlier:

```
Main thread ID:
46965006517856
emit_sig thread ID:
46965006517856
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

Here's more or less what's happening in parallel:

```
# main thread                      #worker thread
my_sender.emit_sig('hello')        #slot onTimeout is called
sleep(1)                           #print "onTimeout get called..."
exit(1)                            #emit finish_sig
sys.exit(app.exec_())
# slot terminate_thread is called  #thread ends (t.quit)
```

If you remove `exit(1)`, your program will work, because you create an event loop with `app.exec_()`. The event loop means your program is always waiting to catch signals, and will not stop even if there's nothing left to do. So the thread has plenty of time to end :)

---

In Qt, you usually stop the event loop by closing your main window. Therefore, a cleaner way to implement your thread is:

```
class window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(window,self).__init__(parent)

        t=QThread(self)
        self.my_worker = GenericWorker()
        self.my_worker.moveToThread(t)
        t.start()

        self.my_sender = Sender()
        self.my_sender.send_sig.connect(self.my_worker.onTimeout)
        self.my_sender.terminate_sig.connect(t.quit)

        self.my_worker.finish_sig.connect(self.my_sender.terminate_thread)

        self.my_sender.emit_sig('hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You need `self` to keep a reference to the thread and classes. Otherwise they are destroyed when `__init__` ends.

Comment: Thank you tmoreau! I actually tried removing that `exit(1)` but it just hang there and never stops... But the `self` thing might be the reason that I should try...

Comment: The reason it doesn't stop is the event loop. If you have a window, the program will stop when you close it. But if you don't need any window, you can look at `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: @sunnystate. You're example will work fine as it is, if you remove `exit(1)` (as suggested by tmoreau), and then just add `t.finished.connect(app.quit)`. This will automatically stop the event-loop once the thread has finished, and the script can then exit normally. As an alternative (which is good for debugging non-gui apps), you can add `import signal; signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)` to the top of the script. You can then manually terminate the script with `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @ekhumoro the t.finished.connect is working! Also good to know that Ctrl+C method! Thanks!